# Replacing error #N/A with today's date in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to replace `#N/A` (resulted due to lookup search) with today's date by using the below code however its not working. Could you please advise if this logic works or need to apply some other technique.

```
Const StartRow As Byte=2
LastRow = Range("J" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = StartRow To LastRow

    myValue = Range("B" & i).Value

    If myValue =Specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas,xlErrors) 
          Then Range("B" & i).Value = "=Today()"

  Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replace Error With Date or Now

- The 1st code uses a loop and replaces all error values with 'Date' (current date) or 'Now' (current date and time).
- To use SpecialCells you do not loop through the rows, you apply it to the whole range. This is shown in the 2nd code.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub replaceWithDate()

    ' Constants
    Const LastRowCol As Variant = "J"  ' Last Row Column Index
    Const StartRow As Long = 2         ' Start Row Number
    Const CriteriaCol As Variant = "B" ' Criteria Column Index
    
    ' Define the row of the last non-blank cell in column 'J' ('LastRow').
    Dim LastRow
    LastRow = Range(LastRowCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Additional variables to be used in 'For Next' loop.
    Dim myValue As Variant ' Current Value
    Dim i As Long          ' Row Counter
    
    ' Loop through rows.
    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        ' Write each value to Current Value.
        myValue = Range(CriteriaCol & i).Value
        ' Test if Current Value contains an error value.
        If IsError(myValue) Then
            ' Write 'Today()'
            'Range(CriteriaCol & i).Value = "=Today()"
            ' If you use the previous line, then when you open
            ' the worksheet tomorrow, it will have tomorrow's date.
            ' Write 'Date'. You can also use 'Now' to include time.
            Range(CriteriaCol & i).Value = Date ' Now
            ' Additionally you can change the number format:
            ' e.g. for Date
            'Range(CriteriaCol & i).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            ' e.g. for Now
            'Range(CriteriaCol & i).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub replaceWithDateSpecialCells()

    ' Constants
    Const LastRowCol As Variant = "J"  ' Last Row Column Index
    Const StartRow As Long = 2         ' Start Row Number
    Const CriteriaCol As Variant = "B" ' Criteria Column Index

    ' Define the row of the last non-blank cell in column 'J' ('LastRow').
    Dim LastRow
    LastRow = Range(LastRowCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Define Criteria Range ('rng').
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(CriteriaCol & StartRow, CriteriaCol & LastRow)
    
    ' Apply 'SpecialCells'.
    On Error Resume Next
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Value = Date
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the specific `#N/A` error using the `WorksheetFunction` method of the Application class.

```
For i = StartRow To LastRow
    
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Range("B" & i)) Then
        Range("B" & i).Formula = "=Today()"
    End If
    
Next
```

As I would always say, in every case you should fully qualify your Range objects. Even if you desire to use the `Active...` whatever it is:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(...)
' Or
Set Rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(...)
```

And when using a `For i =` loop as you have done, I always prefer using the `Cells()` property as opposed to using `Range()` as I prefer not having VBA joining strings together in every loop iteration:

```
For i = StartRow To LastRow

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(i, 2)) Then
        Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=Today()"
    End If

Next
```

But I suppose that ultimately comes down to preference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try combining the [`Range.Replace` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Replace) with the [`CVErr` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/cverr-function), like so:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(StartRow,2), ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow,2)).Replace _
    CVErr(xlErrNA), Date, xlWhole
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the next code, please. No iteration needed:

```
  Dim lastRow As Long, sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  sh.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Formula = "=Today()"
```

or in a single code line:

```
Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Formula = "=Today()"
```

Or (without a formula):

```
Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).value = Date
```